# RegEx backtracking

Tags: regex

I'm providing some matches by including Atomic groups in my RegEx `^(?>A|.)*C` over the string `ABC`, which can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/qO2oJ3/1).

In debugger tab all steps that engine tries to reach a successful match is shown but I can not find a reason and have no idea why some steps are taken place. My questions are pictured below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that it's confusing.  When we talk about backtracking, we usually mean the regex engine is moving backward through the text, giving up characters that it had previously consumed.  Your regex only does that once, at step 14, when `(?>A|.)*` has to give up the `C` so the `C` in the regex can match it.

But that debugger also applies the BACKTRACK label to steps where it tries to match something and fails.  That's what's happening at steps 6, 9 and 12, when it tries to match `A` to `B`, then to `C`, then to nothing (the end of the string).  Of course, by that reasoning step 13, where it tries to match `.` to nothing, should be labelled BACKTRACK as well.

RegexBuddy's debugger labels that step as a backtrack.  Here's the output:

[image: RegexBuddy debugger output]

You can see there are fewer steps listed, but don't ask me what it's leaving out.  RegexBuddy gives too little information to determine whether Regex101 is giving too much. :P

I should note that the atomic group has no effect at all in your example. You can switch to a non-capturing group and the output will be exactly the same. ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO2oJ3/2))  If you want to see the effect they have, put the quantifier *inside* the atomic group. ([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qO2oJ3/3))

Comment: Thank you Alan. I've checked RegexBuddy as well before asking my question and you pointed it out nicely. As my first question in picture, *Why a backtrack here?*, I meant in my vision engine takes additional steps which is not necessary at all. I can find no reason why after matching `B` engine has to backtrack and not just go straight forward to match `C`. Saying that I mean I can draw a line from step `8` to `14` and say this is how it should have ended. You may correct me.

Comment: The group can only match one character at a time, and it always has to try `A` first, because that's the first alternative.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Are there some sources out to study around these debugging tips?

Comment: The best possible source is [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/book.html).  Everything you want to know about regexes, written for ordinary people, not computer scientists.

Answer (score 2):

The atomic group `(?>   )*` automatically throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group. It will match (and do not backtrack afterwards) (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible))

Step 7 `.` matches the `B` and the atomic group drops all backtrack positions

Step 8:
As a human reading your string it easy to look forward and see that the last character in your source string is a `C` but the regular expression engine sees the greedy `*` which forces the engine to continue testing characters. At this point the engine can't look past the `C` in your string to see that it's the last character so it must first backtrack to attempt to include `C` in the match, this leads us to why the additional steps 9 thru 13 happen.

```
Step 9 the expression attempts to match the `C` with an `A` but this fails so it backtracks to attempt the alternation
Step 10 the `.` then attempts to match the `C` and succeeds
Step 12 the expression is now testing the end of the string to see if it matches the `A` and fails to match the end of the string  
Step 13 the expression tests the end of the string with a `.` and fails so it backtracks
Step 14 it back tracked so that the `C` at the end of your expression will match the `C` in the input string
```

Comment: Thank you, but you only translated those steps into a human readable way which isn't the answer to my question. I asked why are these steps taken? Why doesn't engine match `C` after step `8` to finish the match? I can't understand your ninth explained step as well. (after matching `B` the expression attempts to match the `C` with an `A`. Why with an `A`?!)

Comment: I updated the question to flesh out what's happening